# How to update Listview's headerView when Cursor is updated?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with headerView, data is held by custom CursorAdapter:

```
View headerView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_item, null);
mListView.addHeaderView(headerView);

mAdapter = new NewsCursorAdapter(this, getItemsCursor());
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//here do some header initialization from cursor
```

Could you please advice how to update header when cursor is changed?
The problem is that data is populated from WebService, and not always exists onCreate()

ListView items are updated perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this yourself. Whatever code is updating the `Cursor` will need to arrange to update your `headerView` as well.

Comment: yep, registering ContentObserver to Cursor works fine! Thanks!